# Java Spark withColumn algebra by example

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark (`spark-core_2.13:3.3.2`) and **Java 11** here (very important, I need Java solutions please, *not* Scala!).

I am reading an Excel spreadsheet into a `Dataset` like so:

```
public void runSpark(MyDataJob dataJob, JavaSparkContext sparkContext) {

    SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().sparkContext(sparkContext.sc()).getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> dataset = session.read()
        .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
        .option("dataAddress", "'My Sheet'!B3:C35")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
        .option("setErrorCellsToFallbackValues", "true")
        .option("usePlainNumberFormat", "false")
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .option("addColorColumns", "true")
        .option("timestampFormat", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        .option("maxRowsInMemory", 100)
        .option("maxByteArraySize", 2147483647)
        .option("tempFileThreshold", 10000000)
        .option("excerptSize", 10)
        .load(dataJob.getFileName());

    dataset.withColumn("CountDiff", ???);

}
```

The spreadsheet has 2 columns in it, `NumFizz` and `NumBuzz`, and hence, I'm guessing the `Dataset` has these columns as well. I need to add a new column that is the difference of these values in each row, meaning if a row's `NumFizz` value is 17, and its `NumBuzz` is 10, then its value in the new column should be 7. Unfortunately, since literally **all** the `withColumn` examples appear to be in Scala, I can't figure out how to do this in Java. I am also open to using Spark SQL if there's a simple solution using that as well. I just need a new `CountDiff` column added to my Dataset that has the difference of these two columns.

**Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?**

I tried to import the `col` functions and pass them in as args but the lack of viable Java examples is blocking me from making headway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
dataset.withColumn("CountDiff", dataset.col("Numfizz").minus(dataset.col("Numbuzz")));
```

[The `Column.minus` docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#minus-java.lang.Object-) show examples of both Scala and Java usage, where scala applies it's magic operator conversion, and Java needs explicit function calls:

```
// Scala: The following selects the difference between people's height and their weight.
people.select( people("height") - people("weight") )

// Java:
people.select( people.col("height").minus(people.col("weight")) );
```

### alternatively use SQL

You can also use SQL to perform express all the transformations you need:

```
dataset.createOrReplaceTempView("my_sheet")

session.sql("
SELECT
*, 
Numfizz - Numbuzz as CountDiff,
... -- other calculations you may need
FROM my_sheet 
").show();
```

When working with SQL you will may find the [docs for SQL functions available in spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html) useful.

Comment: Thank you @botchniaque, what about if I wanted to take the diff of two different **dates**, will `minus` work on dates as well as numerics?

Comment: THere's a [`date_diff`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#datediff-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) function which takes two columns. You may need to cast them to the correct type.

Comment: The other option is to use SQL for all the transformations - this way you can escape the verbosity of the java sdk. I will add an example into my answer